# Analog Sampling using LIBPRU over beaglebone

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, adc

I need to sample analog signal `(50-60Hz)` through `AIN0` on Beaglebone Black.
What I need is a sample size of `10,000` at 1 millisecond sampling rate `(should run for 10 secs)`.

The python example I found in for beaglebone_pru_adc library is as below -

```
import beaglebone_pru_adc as adc
import time

numsamples = 10000 # how many samples to capture

capture = adc.Capture()

capture.oscilloscope_init(adc.OFF_VALUES, numsamples) # captures AIN0 - the first elt in AIN array

capture.cap_delay = 200000  # I don't understand how to write this part to achieve desired sampling rate

capture.start()

for _ in range(10):
        if capture.oscilloscope_is_complete():
                break
        print '.'
        time.sleep(0.1)

capture.stop()
capture.wait()

print 'Saving oscilloscope values to "data.csv"'

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
        for x in capture.oscilloscope_data(numsamples):
                f.write(str(x) + '\n')

print 'done'

capture.close()
```

I think I am wrong somewhere as I don't expect the acquisition to finish before `10 secs`. Any help regarding how to achieve specific sample size at specific sample rate for BB ADC would be great help.